# Documenting Graphql schema using Nestjs Code-first approach

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, nest

Is there a way to add comments to mutations and queries of your schema generated through code first approach of Nestjs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the decorators like @Field, @ObjectType and some others

You can use description : 'some comment'

And then you Will see the comments in graphql playground

Example

```
@ObjectType( {description : 'My class') )
Class Person {
    @Field ( () => ID, { description : ' ID of the user' } ) 
    Id: number
}
```